# how to fix "com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket" error?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to connect mongodb using spring-boot . while i do that, i have got this error

```
     [localhost:27107] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27107
     com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
```

a quick search suggest me to add this in main class

```
      @SpringBootApplication
      @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})
```

After i did that,error got away . but the db has not been created in the mongodb and when i check the spring-boot logs ,there is no log related to mongodb .

Attaching my POM.XML here

```
       <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>
                            org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                        </processor>
                        <logOnlyOnError>true</logOnlyOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please let me know if you can help me

Comment: After adding , @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class}) , it fixed my issue as well

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue - mongo saying it is connected to the DB with ports and clusters and everything, but when it tries to start a monitor on the database the connection was refused. After checking every possible mongo configuration, it turns out the problem was in my firewall - it was blocking my java connections, so when netty tried to connect to mongo, the firewall blocked the connection.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Add this to the main class.

Answer (score -3):

Configuring embedded MongoDB only for tests should get rid of the error.